# What is this anime movie from the 90s where the protagonist in a jet fights an enemy mech?

Tags: orguss

I watched half an anime movie a long time ago and need to identify it so I can catch the whole thing. This would've been from the 90s, possibly very late night on the sci-fi channel.

From what I can remember, a tall, very strong (possibly genetically modified) male character gains control of an absolutely massive mech. He unleashes a set of missiles with the mech that release a chemical which renders down a huge number of people in seconds.
The protagonists fly in a jet straight into the cockpit of the mech. The main character is a male, black hair, mid twenties with a bandage round his eyes, blind. There is a female character, she is mid twenties, has long blue hair, two tendrils of which she seems to press to the main characters head to share her sight with telepathically, as they also seem to float. I also believe there was an old man in the cockpit with them.

The antagonist basically tanks a fight with them, ignores several punches and attacks. Eventually, the hero breaks his neck. When they think they have defeated him, he pops his neck back into place. He is finally defeated when the hero shoots him in the head with assistance.
The ending is the giant robot vanishing, and the woman with blue hair appearing naked in the wilderness, where two more children with the same floating hair things discover her.

I would love to find it, is driving me insane and I have been searching for years.

Comment: Did u check if it s mazinger z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm almost certain this is the 1993 OAV [Super Dimension Century Orguss 02](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=707)

Details escape me, but there is indeed a gigantic mecha near the end that the protoagnists needed to stop. The hero was injured and couldn't see, so his friend (the aforementioned blue haired girl) helped him see by linking him to her eyes using tendrils that come out of her head. That's her in the eye-catch below:

[image: Orguss 02]